# How to use method change password in java android?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

How to use method change password in java android? I use Eclipse for editor

Action button save change password in my class `ChangePassword` :

```
private void ChangeMe(View v) {
    String currPass = CurrentPass.getText().toString();
    String newPassword = newPass.getText().toString();
    String newConfirmPassword = newConfiPass.getText().toString(); 
}
```

Then how command function in class `DatabaseAdapter`?

In class `DatabaseAdapter`, I have one table (user) with 3 columns (id, username, password).

Comment: So using this method you want to change the password in the `Database`?

Comment: update current password

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to check the entered password is correct with the database password field of particular user using userId(id). then fire the update query for update the old password with new entered password

```
UPDATE TABLE TABLE_NAME set password = newPassword WHERE id = userId(pass userid)
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Can you give me simple example?

Answer (score 0):

First  check newPassword and newConfirmPassword is same or not then go for checking the current password and userid is valid or not then if valid use update statement as stated above